# how to obtain an value from the picker list and perform calculation?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I need to create two Dropdown Lists (picker view) and retrive the values selected by the user in the two drop down list and perform calculations on them ?
Is it possible to create an dropdown list in Xcode ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a two-component picker view.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 2;
}
```

Say you have two arrays, self.firstArray and self.secondArray to populate the two components.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
if (component == 0) {
    UILabel *numberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    NSString *numberString = [self.firstArray objectAtIndex:row];
    numberLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    numberLabel.text = numberString;
    return numberLabel;
} else {
    UILabel *alphabetLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    NSString *alphabet = [self.secondArray objectAtIndex:row];
    alphabetLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    alphabetLabel.text = alphabet;
    return alphabetLabel;
}
}
```

Then you can get to the user selected values like this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:   (NSInteger)component
{
NSLog(@"selected number: %@", self.firstArray[[self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]);
NSLog(@"selected alphabet: %@", self.secondArray[[self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]);
}
```